# jQuery for Drupal 7 Views Search Highlighting

Tags: views, javascript

I'm trying to add highlighting to my Drupal 7 Views-based search interface, so that when a user search for a word, words, or phrase, whatever they searched for is highlighted in the search results.

I decided to use jQuery and [specifically this library](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) : highlight.

I put the above jquery in my theme's /js folder and then added the following code to my template.php file:

```
    // add jquery.highlight-5.js just to views
    function trendtrack_views_pre_render(&$view) {
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'trendtrack') . 
'/js/jquery.highlight-5.js');
    }
```

That seems to be loading just fine. I also added the following to my stylesheet:

```
.highlight { background-color: yellow }
```

The only thing I'm missing and that I'm unsure of is the jQuery code itself. Does anyone know what I should change in the below jQuery code to make it work with Drupal Views search results?

Note: My search interface is using a variable called 'keys' in the url, appended with whatever the user search for, so for example when a user clicks the submit button to search the url will look something like this:

```
http://localhost/search?keys=security
```

Here's the jquery code in question:

```
    jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat) {
     function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
      var skip = 0;
      if (node.nodeType == 3) {
       var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
       pos -= (node.data.substr(0, pos).toUpperCase().length - 
node.data.substr(0, pos).length);
       if (pos >= 0) {
        var spannode = document.createElement('span');
        spannode.className = 'highlight';
        var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
        var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
        var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
        spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
        middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
        skip = 1;
       }
      }
      else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && 
!/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
       for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
        i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
       }
      }
      return skip;
     }
     return this.length && pat && pat.length ? this.each(function() {
      innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
     }) : this;
    };
```